# Any easy way to check usage of published services?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

In a given AX 2012 R3 production running system, is there an easy way to analyse usage of ax services from external systems? AX store access logs in some place?

A similar information that you can get for example analizing IIS logs.

Like who calls, when, what, response time, result, headers, etc...

Comment: Die you take a look at [Monitoring services and AIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/monitoring-services-and-aif)?

Comment: I will have a look. History form looks promising on paper. Not sure if it would require proper configuration. Ie maybe some service is configured in a way that bypass this functionality...